# PHP XMLReader not loading some xml nodes

Tags: php, xml-parsing, xmlreader

This is the xml:

```xml
<Root xmlns:sql='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql'>
<Truserv>

    <Item item_nbr="100024" srp_cost="11.99" member_cost="4.90" ds_cost="4.08" short_description="36&quot; Bent SB Axe Handle" vendor_id="74658" dpt_code="L " class_code="14" subclass_code="36" vendor_name="LINK HANDLE DIV OF SEYMOUR" upc="25545100091" long_description="36&quot;, Homeowner Bent Single Bit Axe Handle, For 3 To 5 LB Axes, Good Weight Hickory, Natural Wax Finish, 1 Wood Wedge Included, Hang Up Hook In Handle For Pegboard Display." weight="1.50" length="0.27" width="0.60" height="3.13" pack_weight="18.60" pack_length="3.20" pack_width="7.20" pack_height="37.50" retail_pack_qty="1" member_pack_qty="12" member_pack_type="B" member_break_pack="Y" model="100-09" item_picture_id="100024" country_code="US" to_be_discontinued="N" retail_uom="EA " Edit_Divisor="1" Exclusive_Brand_Code=""/>

    <Item item_nbr="100183" srp_cost="16.99" member_cost="10.61" ds_cost="10.64" short_de
scription="Lav Pop Up Assembly" vendor_id="5967" dpt_code="A " class_code="38" subclass_code="11" vendor_name="UNITED STATES HDW MFG/U S HA" upc="16356025802" long_description="1-1/4&quot;, Chrome Finish, Lavatory Pop Up Assembly, With Push Rod, No Overflow, ABS Plastic Top &amp; Body." weight="0.54" length="2.31" width="3.75" height="15.38" pack_weight="17.50" pack_length="21.75" pack_width="8.73" pack_height="17.13" retail_pack_qty="1" member_pack_qty="24" member_pack_type="B" member_break_pack="Y" model="P139C" item_picture_id="100183" country_code="US" to_be_discontinued="N" retail_uom="EA " Edit_Divisor="1" Exclusive_Brand_Code=""/>

</Truserv>
```

And this is the PHP Code:

```php
echo "<pre>";
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('temp2.xml');
while (@$reader->read()) {
    echo $reader->getAttribute("item_nbr");
    echo "\n";
}
$reader->close();
echo "</pre>";
```

The problem is, it is only giving some(very few) nodes and for some reason it is not loading most of the nodes. For instance, take the above xml file, it is only loading 1st node (which has item_nbr="100024") and not the last one.

Any ideas why it is happening?

XML File is heavy, its 500mb+ in size and this is why i am using XMLReader.

Thanks!

Comment: either add the solution as an answer and accept it or delete the question altogether please. thanks.

Comment: @gordon i tried but it says wait for 8 hours. I'll fix it after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it myself, the problem was with the newline \n character, which got into my xml file using the php `fseek` for fetching some lines from the xml doc, due to its big size. And in result i received data along with the newline characters which was not letting the xmlreader parser to parse any further.

now correct xml file is:

```xml
<Root xmlns:sql='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql'>
<Truserv>

    <Item item_nbr="100024" srp_cost="11.99" member_cost="4.90" ds_cost="4.08" short_description="36&quot; Bent SB Axe Handle" vendor_id="74658" dpt_code="L " class_code="14" subclass_code="36" vendor_name="LINK HANDLE DIV OF SEYMOUR" upc="25545100091" long_description="36&quot;, Homeowner Bent Single Bit Axe Handle, For 3 To 5 LB Axes, Good Weight Hickory, Natural Wax Finish, 1 Wood Wedge Included, Hang Up Hook In Handle For Pegboard Display." weight="1.50" length="0.27" width="0.60" height="3.13" pack_weight="18.60" pack_length="3.20" pack_width="7.20" pack_height="37.50" retail_pack_qty="1" member_pack_qty="12" member_pack_type="B" member_break_pack="Y" model="100-09" item_picture_id="100024" country_code="US" to_be_discontinued="N" retail_uom="EA " Edit_Divisor="1" Exclusive_Brand_Code=""/>

    <Item item_nbr="100183" srp_cost="16.99" member_cost="10.61" ds_cost="10.64" short_description="Lav Pop Up Assembly" vendor_id="5967" dpt_code="A " class_code="38" subclass_code="11" vendor_name="UNITED STATES HDW MFG/U S HA" upc="16356025802" long_description="1-1/4&quot;, Chrome Finish, Lavatory Pop Up Assembly, With Push Rod, No Overflow, ABS Plastic Top &amp; Body." weight="0.54" length="2.31" width="3.75" height="15.38" pack_weight="17.50" pack_length="21.75" pack_width="8.73" pack_height="17.13" retail_pack_qty="1" member_pack_qty="24" member_pack_type="B" member_break_pack="Y" model="P139C" item_picture_id="100183" country_code="US" to_be_discontinued="N" retail_uom="EA " Edit_Divisor="1" Exclusive_Brand_Code=""/>

</Truserv>
```